# After adding flags to enum: Wcf error: Error 5 Custom tool error: Failed to generate code for the service reference 'MyService'

Tags: wcf, enums, datacontract, flags

on my WCF Service I just change an enum from:

```
    /// <summary>
/// The DocumentState enum.
/// </summary>
[DataContract]
public enum DocumentState
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Undefined.
    /// </summary>
    [EnumMember]
    Undefined,

    /// <summary>
    /// OK.
    /// </summary>
    [EnumMember]
    Ok
}
```

to:

```
    /// <summary>
/// The DocumentState enum.
/// </summary>
[DataContract]
[Flags]
public enum DocumentState
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Undefined.
    /// </summary>
    [EnumMember]
    Undefined = 0,

    /// <summary>
    /// OK.
    /// </summary>
    [EnumMember]
    Ok = 1
}
```

On the client side I update the WCF References without any Problems but after rebuild I get:

Error 5 Custom tool error: Failed to generate code for the service reference 'MyService'.  Please check other error and warning messages for details

Whats wrong with this flag enum?

**UPDATE:**

Ok.. in the warrnings I found this but this doesn't really helps me:

Warning 1   Custom tool warning: Cannot import wsdl:portType
Detail: An exception was thrown while running a WSDL import extension: System.ServiceModel.Description.DataContractSerializerMessageContractImporter
Error: Referenced type 'TestSolution.Test.Entities.Documents.Document, TestSolution.Test.Entities, Version=1.1.78.7965, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7ad0fddf5c57b9b3' with data contract name 'Document' in namespace 'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/TestSolution.Test.Entities.Documents' cannot be used since it does not match imported DataContract. Need to exclude this type from referenced types.

XPath to Error Source: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://tempuri.org/']/wsdl:portType[@name='IDocumentService']   c:\TFS1\TestSolution - Test\Test\Test.Core\Service References\DocumentService\Reference.svcmap  1   1   Test.Core
Warning 2   Custom tool warning: Cannot import wsdl:binding
Detail: There was an error importing a wsdl:portType that the wsdl:binding is dependent on.

XPath to wsdl:portType: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://tempuri.org/']/wsdl:portType[@name='IDocumentService']
XPath to Error Source: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://tempuri.org/']/wsdl:binding[@name='NetTcpEndpoint']  c:\TFS1\TestSolution - Test\Test\Test.Core\Service References\DocumentService\Reference.svcmap  1   1   Test.Core
Warning 3   Custom tool warning: Cannot import wsdl:port

Detail: There was an error importing a wsdl:binding that the wsdl:port is dependent on.
XPath to wsdl:binding: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://tempuri.org/']/wsdl:binding[@name='NetTcpEndpoint']
XPath to Error Source: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://tempuri.org/']/wsdl:service[@name='DocumentService']/wsdl:port[@name='NetTcpEndpoint']   c:\TFS1\TestSolution - Test\Test\Test.Core\Service References\DocumentService\Reference.svcmap  1   1   Test.Core
Error   4   Custom tool error: Failed to generate code for the service reference 'DocumentService'.  Please check other error and warning messages for details. c:\TFS1\TestSolution - Test\Test\Test.Core\Service References\DocumentService\Reference.svcmap  1   1   Test.Core

Comment: UPDATE:Some additional informations for you:

- I am using net.tcp binding
- The enum is using in min. 50 places (with out the flags attribute) already on the wcf service and on the client
- When I create a new enum with the same name but with a 2 at the end of the name all works great!

What means really the warnings about the "wsdl:portType" / "wsdl:binding" / "wsdl:port" ????

Answer (score 0):

When you added the `Flag` attribute, you changed the way the Enum is stored and made variables of that type capable of holding multiple values. This [MSDN post](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347875%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) explains the details on how WCF handles this. Unless you actually intend to make that Enum function as a flag field, I'd get rid of it since it needless complicates Enum meaning.

Comment: Still don't see the Problem :(

Comment: Ok.. in the warrnings I found this but this doesn't really helps me:

Comment: I think the simple solution is to remove the `Flag` attribute and the Enum as before. By adding it, you changed the data type of the Enum which is causing a breaking changed to you clients.

Comment: In that case, introduce a new `Enum DocStateFlags` and change your server and client side code to use the new Enum. There is no simple way to convert your current Enum to a `Flag` type without re-writing code.

Comment: And just found a new warning in the project:

Warning 1 Custom tool warning: An item with the same key has already been added. C:\Test\Service References\DocumentService\Reference.svcmap 1 1 Test.Core

Comment: Hi!

finally I found the problem.

1. I have a references to the contracts Project in the Project that has the Wcf Refs....But this wasn't the real Problem (I check it with the Windows Form app).
2. The Contract Project has a IDocumentCallback Interface in it that the service use:

[ServiceContract(CallbackContract = typeof(IDocumentCallback), SessionMode = SessionMode.Required)]

After refactor this interafce to another Project all works again!

But what was the REAL Problem?